# Hook type casting to dict in Python

Tags: python, casting, flask, hook

In a nutshell I have a class `Session` inherited from `dict` (in fact, this class overrides `flask.SecureCookieSession` class). Also I have a client code that's doing something like this:

```
session_data = dict(session)
```

And I want to somehow hook this `to dict` conversion in order to inject few lines of code modifying session data before serializing. How can I do it in Python?

**UPD:** To clarify: I don't want to return anything different from a dict object from the `dict()` call. I just want this call invokes a special method of my session object before getting a data to convert it to the dict object. Something like `__to_dict(self)` hook.

Answer (score 4):

If we look at the [source code for `dict`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/dictobject.c#l2006) we can see that when `dict` is called with a `dict` subclass, no user methods are called:

```
int
PyDict_Merge(PyObject *a, PyObject *b, int override)
{
    /* ... */
    if (PyDict_Check(b)) {
        other = (PyDictObject*)b;
        /* ...
           Only other->ma_keys and other->ma_values are used.
           No user-defined methods/attributes are accessed.
           ...
         */
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

This is a CPython-specific performance optimization.

In order to be able to detect when your dictionary is being copied, you should avoid inheriting from `dict` and instead provide a mapping-like object. Consider inheriting from [MutableMapping](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping) or [UserDict](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict).

Comment: Hm, I don't want to return anything else from the `dict` call. I just want this call invokes a special method of my session object before getting a data to convert it to the dict object. Something like `__to_dict__(self)` hook.

Comment: I got your update. However, it's not my decision to inherit from `dict`. It's a part of the flask session implementation ([1](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/6e77cd709e16f7d1d654f67a5fc82e54bceae432/flask/sessions.py#L112), [2](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/285e300f7f5806253000f13b36e87ef10eccfae7/werkzeug/datastructures.py#L1941)). Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @Ostrovski: you can tell Flask to use your own Session class. It can be a *wrapper* around SecureCookieSession.

Comment: I've already used my own session class that is inherited from `CallbackDict` and `SessionMixin` (not directly from `dict` really). And now I tend to use my own CallbackDict implementation which will be inherited from `UserDict` class maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than overloading the builtin function `dict()`, it's best practice to just write and call your own function, like:

```
def my_dict_func(session):
    fixed_session = do_extra_stuff(session)
    return dict(fixed_session)
```

Comment: I don't want to overload builtin function. And yes, I can introduce a `to_dict` method into my session class and then rewrite the client code to use `session_data = session.to_dict()`. But I want to save original behavior because I'm not sure that flask doesn't use such `dict()` casting in other places.

Comment: Can you add the `do_stuff()` step to the serialization process, rather than the `dict()` step?

Comment: Yeah, I can add such step in this particular place. However I can't relay on this solution because I don't know (and can't predict for the all next versions of flask) entire session's work flow.

Comment: Well you'll never be able to predict future versions of any library. I'm not sure what you mean by "I don't know ... all session's work flow".

Comment: And that's exactly why interfaces are needed. If I conserve expected behavior for my session implementation and don't break the interface, I can relay on the next versions as soon as they provide the backward compatibility. But as soon as I break behavior of `dict()` call for my session object (by replacing it with extra method `to_dict()`) I'll break the session class interface.

Comment: Interfaces? Just what language are you writing in? ;) Given the updates, I like @AndreaCorbellini's suggestion for [UserDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict). Note that [multiple inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance) in Python is possible, so that you can inherit from both `UserDict` and the `flask.SecureCookieSession`

Comment: In my universe interface is rather an abstract idea than a programming language feature.